# Modified Green's function

Tags: functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

The question is find the modified Green's functions for  $$u''+u=f(x)$$ with boundary conditions $$u(0)=0, u(\pi)=0$$

I know I should modified the Green's function as $$Lg(x,\zeta)=\delta(x-\zeta)-\sum_1^n\alpha_i\psi_i(x)$$ and $\alpha_i$ span the nullspace of adjoint of $L$, but then what should I do? Can somebody give me a specific answer?